# discord.js playing audio on multiple servers

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I made a test test bot for discord.js using Node.js / ffmpeg, to play a radio station in a channel on discord and there are no problems there, however i was thinking about how it would stream the same station to multiple servers/channels efficiently.

For example, if I am playing it on "Discord server one":

```
var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
    console.log("joined channel");
    const dispatcher = connection.playArbitraryInput('http://philae.shoutca.st:8950/live', { volume: 0.5 });

    dispatcher.on("end", end => {
      console.log("left channel");
      voiceChannel.leave();
     });
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

However if i want to play it on another server that my bot is a member of, do i need to create the audio stream again?

If so that kinda sux. My bot would have to encode the stream seperatly for each instance?

I would like to know if there is any way i can reuse the audio stream and restream it so that if I had my bot in 100 channels its only one download instance of the stream and 100 uploads

I haope i am making sense but let me make some fake code to try help explain:

lets say instead i could do something like this:

```
let cachedAudioStream = cacheArbitraryInput('http://philae.shoutca.st:8950/live', {});
```

then for every outgoing instance:

```
connection1.playArbitraryInput(cachedAudioStream, { volume: 0.5 });
connection2.playArbitraryInput(cachedAudioStream, { volume: 0.8 });
connection3.playArbitraryInput(cachedAudioStream, { volume: 1 });
```

and so on

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the stream is managed by Discord.js (you only give a link, and Discord.js uses FFMPEG to handle it), you can't do it without modifying the Discord.js code.

Your question is relevant but I don't think it's feasible, at least if you uses Discord.js. You can still open an issue on their [Github repository](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js) to ask them.

Comment: yes its unfortunate, would love to make it more efficient but seems for now at least that every new audio connection creates a totally new instance both down and up.

Answer (score 1):

discord.js has a '[Voice Broadcast](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-broadcasts.html#example-usage)' for stuff like radio bots. Yes, you do have to connect the call to the broadcast but that's all.